# Using OR for two possible errors inside try catch in JS

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have to possible error inside a try catch block like below:

```
try {
  let result = A || B;
  // use result
} catch(e) {
  console.log("ERROR")
}
```

Each of A or B can throw error. Waht I need is I want to refer to catch only in situation both A and B throw error. is it possible?

**Note: I know that I can use separate try-catch for each of them. I was wondering if I can write it inside just single try-catch block

Comment: `||` won't even necessarily execute both. You'd need something like `try { A } catch (e) { errors++ }`, and afterwards check `if (errors >= 2)`…

Comment: Yes, separate them into different try-catch blocks and write the correct logic around them.

Comment: I know that I can use separate try-catch for each of them. I was wondering if I can write it inside just single try-catch block

Comment: No. You can figure out whether A *or* B failed by executing them separately and setting a flag, but in case A failed you won't know whether B would also have failed, since it'll go to the catch immediately. If you definitely want to execute both, you need to do so in two separate `try..catch`.